# Cloning Windows 7 installation from MBR to GPT drive and make it bootable

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning, mbr, gpt

I've seen threads on similar topics - such as [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/443561/clone-a-windows-installation-to-a-3tb-hard-drive-mbr-to-gpt) - but the answers never seem to solve how to make it bootable.

I have Win 7 64-bit on a PC installed on a 2tb MBR volume. The motherboard is UEFI compatible.

I just installed a secondary internal 3TB drive which will be partitioned as GPT.

Is there a relatively easy way to clone my installation over to the new drive and have that drive be bootable?

I have used EaseUS Partition Master to clone the C volume to the D volume, but that would not boot and I assume the issue is that one is MBR and one is GPT.

Is there a process to do this?

Comment: I thought easus freeware version does not support GPT, did you use the paid version?

Comment: No. I actually used EaseUS Todo Backup Free, not Partition Master.

Comment: I do not know what to tell you, there is a round-about method. Install a fresh clean OS on the intended drive, insure the bootability and functionality (don't bother with drivers and updates). Then Image clone the partition (i did not say disk) using a image file, which will be all the files including the registry. then push the image onto the clean install partition (unselect mbr or boot info). It will not effect the boot (usually). stupid way , but it isn't likely to fail, and you previously test booting to it before putting the image of the System partition on.

Answer (score 2):

See the following page:

https://gitorious.org/tianocore_uefi_duet_builds/pages/Windows_x64_BIOS_to_UEFI

In brief, what you want to do is possible. Since you've cloned the installation to another (GPT) disk, you can skip the stuff about converting from MBR to GPT; all you need to do is to install the Windows EFI boot loader, which is summarized in section 3. (It looks like the page has been condensed since I last read it, so you'll need to follow external links and figure out the precise commands to use yourself based on those links.)