# Change Windows 10 installation from one physical drive to other

Tags: windows, hard-drive, windows-10, ssd, clone

I have an old PC with a HDD of 500GB with Windows 10 installation and is almost 90% filled with. The HDD is now fairly old and response time of Windows has become too slow.
I am planning to upgrade PC with with new faster but small capacity SSD along with the existing HDD that can hold Windows 10 installation and will provide much improved response time.

What I want to know is, if I install the SSD is it possible to move Windows 10 installation from HDD to SSD, if possible how?
I do not have the DVD or any recovery disc for the current installation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The word you're looking for is "clone" these may help- [1](http://superuser.com/questions/99211/free-way-to-clone-hdd-to-ssd) [2](http://superuser.com/questions/443561/clone-a-windows-installation-to-a-3tb-hard-drive-mbr-to-gpt)

Answer (score 1):

Things you will need:-

- 1 USB drive with GPartED (Gnome partition editor),
- 1 USB drive with Clonezilla,
- A disk to backup to in case of a mistake,
- Administrator privileges on the PC,
- Some knowledge of finding Windows settings,
- Some knowledge of your motherboard BIOS.

Now the method I use:-

1. Run Defraggler and Ccleaner, delete large unneeded files and run disk clean-up (clean up system files too).
2. Run `powercfg –h off` in elevated CMD.
3. Turn off file indexing.
4. Check pagefile and adjust to 200 – 5000Mb.
5. Backup if necessary.
6. Reboot into GPartEd and reduce disk size to 20Gb below SSD size, making sure Windows partition is the last partition on the disk.
7. Reboot into Windows and allow ChkDsk to run.
8. Reboot into Clonezilla, select expert mode, and select icds (skip disk size check).
9. Use partition table from image.
10. Reboot to Windows and allow ChkDsk to run again and log in to Windows.
11. Restart when prompt pops up.
12. Log in and run `fsutil behaviour query disabledeletenotify`. This should return 0. If not rerun Windows Experience Index which should detect SSD.
13. Change BIOS mode to AHCI. In elevated CMD, run `bcdedit /set {current} safeboot minimal`
14. Restart the PC and change to AHCI in BIOS (somewhere in storage settings)
15. Boot into Windows safe mode and run `bcdedit /deletevalue {current} safeboot`

Enjoy your new, much faster PC.