# GPT Boot disk black screen blinking cursor

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10, boot, partitioning, gpt

Ive recently bought a new HDD and cloned my old system disk onto it. System (64bit Win10) booted fine after this.

Now since the new disk is 3TB, I decided to convert it to GPT in order to be able to use the full size as a single partition and used Aomei Partition Assistant to do so. Now for some reason when booting I only get a black screen with a blinking underscore.

Im was pretty sure my mobo should support UEFI before converting, as "UEFI BIOS" is mentioned several times in the materials (mobo is Asus ROG Maximus IV Gene-Z). However, I cant find any "Enable UEFI" option in the bios settings.

Can this have anything to do with the order of the partitions on the disk?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Welcome to SU , You need to create a new partition EFI formatted F32 size = 500M , Then install the bootloader on it

Comment: @GAD3R converting to GPT created a 101M fat32 partition with "boot, esp" flags (used 827.5K), is this the partition you mean? However it placed it inbetween other partitions, aka my partitions are: NTFS 2T, unallocated 7M, fat32 boot esp 101M, unallocated 746M. Could the order of these be the problem?

Comment: Yes , see the recommanded configuration [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh825702.aspx)

Comment: @GAD3R hm this is weird. Ive moved the partition using Aomei, and it shows first both there and in Easus, however, after entering system troubleshooting and cmd via recovery disk, in diskpart, C shows up as volume 0 and the 100M F32 partition as volume 1

Comment: didnt manage to get it working after several hours... giving up... just going to format and clone again, leaving it as MBR and splitting it into two partitions, 2TB and 1TB

Comment: Managed to fix thanks to this: http://superuser.com/a/475954/669142